# android splinting Strings

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement, split

I I have is a server witch is sending me a String such as "False~False~False~True~False~True~False~" or something of that nature so what I have done is I did a split on that string to the "~" so my code was `String[] AString = A2MCString.split("~");` with the new string array I have I went to a cheack to see if each sections was true or false using an if else statment

```
if (AString[0] == "True") {
Log.d("ClientActivity","Light ON");
On1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_on);
}
else Log.d("ClientActivity","Light OFF");
```

however even when the server send me true in the first part of my string array the array still bounces to else saying that it is false even though it was true? Any help for my problem thanks!

Answer (score 5):

When comparing strings in java you must use the `equals` method. In your case something like

```
if (AString[0].equals("True")) {
    Log.d("ClientActivity","Light ON");
    On1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_on);
}
else Log.d("ClientActivity","Light OFF");
```

When using the == operator on objects (in java a string is an object), it is comparing if the two object references point to the same object.